# Swift hash a string using hash_hmac with ripemd160

Tags: objective-c, swift, hash, cryptography

I'm trying to hash a String in Swift 3 (and/or objective C) using `ripemd160` to emulate the output of the following php:

```
$string = 'string';
$key = 'test';

hash_hmac('ripemd160', $string, $key);

// outputs: 37241f2513c60ae4d9b3b8d0d30517445f451fa5
```

**So far:**

I've tried looking into `hash_hmac` functionality that I can find, such as: 
[Implementing HMAC and SHA1 encryption in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970807/implementing-hmac-and-sha1-encryption-in-swift)

```
enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, RIPEMD160

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        case .RIPEMD160:
            result = kCCHmacAlgRIPEMD160
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String {
    func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, Int(strlen(cKey!)), cData!, Int(strlen(cData!)), &result)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }
}
```

and to implement:

`let hmacResult: String = "myStringToHMAC".hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA1, key: "foo")`

This enables me to successfully hash a string using hmac and one of the encryption algorithms provided by `<CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>`

**Issue**

The issue is that library doesn't provide support for `ripemd160`, so how can I add this support in to be able to accomplish what I need?

---

There is a question exactly the same as this but in Java here, you can see how that was solved and exactly what I'm looking for but this time using Swift 3:
[Hash a string in Java emulating the php function hash_hmac using ripemd160 with a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568562/hash-a-string-in-java-emulating-the-php-function-hash-hmac-using-ripemd160-with)

Comment: It's Swift 1.something but it shouldn't be impossible to port it to Swift 3 https://rosettacode.org/wiki/RIPEMD-160#Swift

Comment: @JeremyP: I did that, and it turned out to be very slow (factor >50), compared to a C-based solution (as suggested by Jens), or my Swift translation of C code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a (self-contained) pure **Swift 5** implementation of the RIPEMD-160 hash function and the 
corresponding HMAC-RIPEMD-160 message authentication code. It has been tested with
all test vectors on the [RIPEMD-160 page](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160.html) (tested on
macOS, 32-bit iOS, 64-bit iOS).

The code for **Swift 3** can be found in the edit history.

This is a translation of the reference implementation
[rmd160.h](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160/ps/AB-9601/rmd160.h),
[rmd160.c](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160/ps/AB-9601/rmd160.c)
from the RIPEMD-160 page from C to Swift. I translated the helper macros and the `compress()`
function (the "heart" of the algorithm) as "verbatim" as possible. This allowed me to
copy/paste large C code segments and make only minor adjustments for Swift.

The `update()` and `finalize()` methods provide a streaming interface, similar to that
of the CommonCrypto functions.

**RIPEMD160.swift:**

```
import Foundation

public struct RIPEMD160 {

    private var MDbuf: (UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32)
    private var buffer: Data
    private var count: Int64 // Total # of bytes processed.

    public init() {
        MDbuf = (0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476, 0xc3d2e1f0)
        buffer = Data()
        count = 0
    }

    private mutating func compress(_ X: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) {

        // *** Helper functions (originally macros in rmd160.h) ***

        /* ROL(x, n) cyclically rotates x over n bits to the left */
        /* x must be of an unsigned 32 bits type and 0 <= n < 32. */
        func ROL(_ x: UInt32, _ n: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
            return (x << n) | ( x >> (32 - n))
        }

        /* the five basic functions F(), G() and H() */

        func F(_ x: UInt32, _ y: UInt32, _ z: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
            return x ^ y ^ z
        }

        func G(_ x: UInt32, _ y: UInt32, _ z: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
            return (x & y) | (~x & z)
        }

        func H(_ x: UInt32, _ y: UInt32, _ z: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
            return (x | ~y) ^ z
        }

        func I(_ x: UInt32, _ y: UInt32, _ z: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
            return (x & z) | (y & ~z)
        }

        func J(_ x: UInt32, _ y: UInt32, _ z: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
            return x ^ (y | ~z)
        }

        /* the ten basic operations FF() through III() */

        func FF(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ F(b, c, d) &+ x
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func GG(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ G(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x5a827999
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func HH(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ H(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x6ed9eba1
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func II(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ I(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x8f1bbcdc
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func JJ(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ J(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0xa953fd4e
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func FFF(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ F(b, c, d) &+ x
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func GGG(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ G(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x7a6d76e9
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func HHH(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ H(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x6d703ef3
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func III(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ I(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x5c4dd124
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        func JJJ(_ a: inout UInt32, _ b: UInt32, _ c: inout UInt32, _ d: UInt32, _ e: UInt32, _ x: UInt32, _ s: UInt32) {
            a = a &+ J(b, c, d) &+ x &+ 0x50a28be6
            a = ROL(a, s) &+ e
            c = ROL(c, 10)
        }

        // *** The function starts here ***

        var (aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) = MDbuf
        var (aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee) = MDbuf

        /* round 1 */
        FF(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 0], 11)
        FF(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 1], 14)
        FF(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 2], 15)
        FF(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 3], 12)
        FF(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 4],  5)
        FF(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 5],  8)
        FF(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 6],  7)
        FF(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 7],  9)
        FF(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 8], 11)
        FF(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 9], 13)
        FF(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[10], 14)
        FF(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[11], 15)
        FF(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[12],  6)
        FF(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[13],  7)
        FF(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[14],  9)
        FF(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[15],  8)

        /* round 2 */
        GG(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 7],  7)
        GG(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 4],  6)
        GG(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[13],  8)
        GG(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 1], 13)
        GG(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[10], 11)
        GG(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 6],  9)
        GG(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[15],  7)
        GG(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 3], 15)
        GG(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[12],  7)
        GG(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 0], 12)
        GG(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 9], 15)
        GG(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 5],  9)
        GG(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 2], 11)
        GG(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[14],  7)
        GG(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[11], 13)
        GG(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 8], 12)

        /* round 3 */
        HH(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 3], 11)
        HH(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[10], 13)
        HH(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[14],  6)
        HH(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 4],  7)
        HH(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 9], 14)
        HH(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[15],  9)
        HH(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 8], 13)
        HH(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 1], 15)
        HH(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 2], 14)
        HH(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 7],  8)
        HH(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 0], 13)
        HH(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 6],  6)
        HH(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[13],  5)
        HH(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[11], 12)
        HH(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 5],  7)
        HH(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[12],  5)

        /* round 4 */
        II(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 1], 11)
        II(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 9], 12)
        II(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[11], 14)
        II(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[10], 15)
        II(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 0], 14)
        II(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 8], 15)
        II(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[12],  9)
        II(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 4],  8)
        II(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[13],  9)
        II(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 3], 14)
        II(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 7],  5)
        II(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[15],  6)
        II(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[14],  8)
        II(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 5],  6)
        II(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 6],  5)
        II(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 2], 12)

        /* round 5 */
        JJ(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 4],  9)
        JJ(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 0], 15)
        JJ(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[ 5],  5)
        JJ(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 9], 11)
        JJ(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 7],  6)
        JJ(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[12],  8)
        JJ(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 2], 13)
        JJ(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[10], 12)
        JJ(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[14],  5)
        JJ(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[ 1], 12)
        JJ(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[ 3], 13)
        JJ(&aa, bb, &cc, dd, ee, X[ 8], 14)
        JJ(&ee, aa, &bb, cc, dd, X[11], 11)
        JJ(&dd, ee, &aa, bb, cc, X[ 6],  8)
        JJ(&cc, dd, &ee, aa, bb, X[15],  5)
        JJ(&bb, cc, &dd, ee, aa, X[13],  6)

        /* parallel round 1 */
        JJJ(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 5],  8)
        JJJ(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[14],  9)
        JJJ(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 7],  9)
        JJJ(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 0], 11)
        JJJ(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 9], 13)
        JJJ(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 2], 15)
        JJJ(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[11], 15)
        JJJ(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 4],  5)
        JJJ(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[13],  7)
        JJJ(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 6],  7)
        JJJ(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[15],  8)
        JJJ(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 8], 11)
        JJJ(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 1], 14)
        JJJ(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[10], 14)
        JJJ(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 3], 12)
        JJJ(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[12],  6)

        /* parallel round 2 */
        III(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 6],  9)
        III(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[11], 13)
        III(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 3], 15)
        III(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 7],  7)
        III(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 0], 12)
        III(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[13],  8)
        III(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 5],  9)
        III(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[10], 11)
        III(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[14],  7)
        III(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[15],  7)
        III(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 8], 12)
        III(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[12],  7)
        III(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 4],  6)
        III(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 9], 15)
        III(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 1], 13)
        III(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 2], 11)

        /* parallel round 3 */
        HHH(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[15],  9)
        HHH(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 5],  7)
        HHH(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 1], 15)
        HHH(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 3], 11)
        HHH(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 7],  8)
        HHH(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[14],  6)
        HHH(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 6],  6)
        HHH(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 9], 14)
        HHH(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[11], 12)
        HHH(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 8], 13)
        HHH(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[12],  5)
        HHH(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 2], 14)
        HHH(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[10], 13)
        HHH(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 0], 13)
        HHH(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 4],  7)
        HHH(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[13],  5)

        /* parallel round 4 */
        GGG(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 8], 15)
        GGG(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 6],  5)
        GGG(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 4],  8)
        GGG(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 1], 11)
        GGG(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 3], 14)
        GGG(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[11], 14)
        GGG(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[15],  6)
        GGG(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 0], 14)
        GGG(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 5],  6)
        GGG(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[12],  9)
        GGG(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 2], 12)
        GGG(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[13],  9)
        GGG(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 9], 12)
        GGG(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 7],  5)
        GGG(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[10], 15)
        GGG(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[14],  8)

        /* parallel round 5 */
        FFF(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[12] ,  8)
        FFF(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[15] ,  5)
        FFF(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[10] , 12)
        FFF(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 4] ,  9)
        FFF(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 1] , 12)
        FFF(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[ 5] ,  5)
        FFF(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[ 8] , 14)
        FFF(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 7] ,  6)
        FFF(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 6] ,  8)
        FFF(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 2] , 13)
        FFF(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[13] ,  6)
        FFF(&aaa, bbb, &ccc, ddd, eee, X[14] ,  5)
        FFF(&eee, aaa, &bbb, ccc, ddd, X[ 0] , 15)
        FFF(&ddd, eee, &aaa, bbb, ccc, X[ 3] , 13)
        FFF(&ccc, ddd, &eee, aaa, bbb, X[ 9] , 11)
        FFF(&bbb, ccc, &ddd, eee, aaa, X[11] , 11)

        /* combine results */
        MDbuf = (MDbuf.1 &+ cc &+ ddd,
                 MDbuf.2 &+ dd &+ eee,
                 MDbuf.3 &+ ee &+ aaa,
                 MDbuf.4 &+ aa &+ bbb,
                 MDbuf.0 &+ bb &+ ccc)
    }

    public mutating func update(data: Data) {
        var X = [UInt32](repeating: 0, count: 16)
        var pos = data.startIndex
        var length = data.count

        // Process remaining bytes from last call:
        if buffer.count > 0 && buffer.count + length >= 64 {
            let amount = 64 - buffer.count
            buffer.append(data[..<amount])
            X.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
                _ = buffer.copyBytes(to: $0)
            }
            compress(X)
            pos += amount
            length -= amount
        }

        // Process 64 byte chunks:
        while length >= 64 {
            X.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
                _ = data[pos..<pos+64].copyBytes(to: $0)
            }
            compress(X)
            pos += 64
            length -= 64
        }

        // Save remaining unprocessed bytes:
        buffer = data[pos...]
        count += Int64(data.count)
    }

    public mutating func finalize() -> Data {
        var X = [UInt32](repeating: 0, count: 16)
        /* append the bit m_n == 1 */
        buffer.append(0x80)
        X.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
            _ = buffer.copyBytes(to: $0)
        }

        if (count & 63) > 55 {
            /* length goes to next block */
            compress(X)
            X = [UInt32](repeating: 0, count: 16)
        }

        /* append length in bits */
        let lswlen = UInt32(truncatingIfNeeded: count)
        let mswlen = UInt32(UInt64(count) >> 32)
        X[14] = lswlen << 3
        X[15] = (lswlen >> 29) | (mswlen << 3)
        compress(X)

        buffer = Data()
        let result = [MDbuf.0, MDbuf.1, MDbuf.2, MDbuf.3, MDbuf.4]
        return result.withUnsafeBytes { Data($0) }
    }
}
```

And here are "one-shot" functions to compute the hash of a message (given as `Data`
or as `String`):

**RIPEMD160-Ext.swift:**

```
import Foundation

public extension RIPEMD160 {

    static func hash(message: Data) -> Data {
        var md = RIPEMD160()
        md.update(data: message)
        return md.finalize()
    }

    static func hash(message: String) -> Data {
        return RIPEMD160.hash(message: message.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }
}
```

Finally, the corresponding message authentication code. The algorithm is taken
from the pseudo-code at
[Wikipedia: Hash-based message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code):

**RIPEMD160-HMAC.swift:**

```
import Foundation

public extension RIPEMD160 {

    static func hmac(key: Data, message: Data) -> Data {

        var key = key
        key.count = 64 // Truncate to 64 bytes or fill-up with zeros.

        let outerKeyPad = Data(key.map { $0 ^ 0x5c })
        let innerKeyPad = Data(key.map { $0 ^ 0x36 })

        var innerMd = RIPEMD160()
        innerMd.update(data: innerKeyPad)
        innerMd.update(data: message)

        var outerMd = RIPEMD160()
        outerMd.update(data: outerKeyPad)
        outerMd.update(data: innerMd.finalize())

        return outerMd.finalize()
    }

    static func hmac(key: Data, message: String) -> Data {
        return RIPEMD160.hmac(key: key, message: message.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }

    static func hmac(key: String, message: String) -> Data {
        return RIPEMD160.hmac(key: key.data(using: .utf8)!, message: message)
    }
}
```

### Examples

To print the message digest as a hex-encoded string, the following method from 
[How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift/40089462#40089462)
can be used:

```
extension Data {
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

Example 1:

```
let msg = "Hello World"
let hash = RIPEMD160.hash(message: msg).hexEncodedString()
print(hash) // a830d7beb04eb7549ce990fb7dc962e499a27230
```

Example 2 (your example):

```
let hmac = RIPEMD160.hmac(key: "test", message: "string").hexEncodedString()
print(hmac) // 37241f2513c60ae4d9b3b8d0d30517445f451fa5
```

Comment: The above code assumes a little-endian architecture (which all current iOS and macOS platforms are). It can be generalized to arbitrary byte order, if necessary.

Comment: Nice! I made a Swift Package with your code, and included tests for all the vector examples on the reference page. https://github.com/darkFunction/SwiftRIPEMD160

Comment: I have migrated a RIPEMD160 impl in Swift 5 (based on the work on Sjors Provoost), which can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Sajjon/cd17a0e09bcc5ff9b1a4d5be3da29b64
However, the answer provided by Martin R here is 10 times faster. But Sjors was easier to migrate to Swift 5. All those `withUnsafeBytes` warnings in Swift 5 was tricky to solve.

Comment: @Sajjon: I have updated the above code to Swift 5, any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Damn, that was fast @MartinR! You rock!

Comment: Here are the test vectors in Swift 5 (Swift 4 compatible I guess) if anyone is interested: https://gist.github.com/Sajjon/95f0c72ca72f0b6985d550b80eff536d

Probably identical to what Martin used when he implemented this...

Comment: @MartinR It would be convenient if your RIPEMD160 was part of CryptoSwift: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift
Do you wanna do a PR? Or should I? Crediting this SO post ofc...

Comment: @Sajjon: I won't have the time, but you are welcome to use that code in any way you like (according to the SO license terms). It may be necessary to include the license terms from the original C code (I am not a license expert).

Answer (score 3):

As you have already figured out `ripemd160` is unsupported in CommonCrypto. Therefore, you need to use some external crypto library. There are (at least) two libraries that you can use in Swift/Objective-C: [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) or [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com).

**OpenSSL**

Here is the code for calculating the hmac hash with ripemd160 using OpenSSL:

```
+ (NSString *)ripemd160WithKey:(NSString *)aKey andData:(NSString *)aData {
   const char* key = [aKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   const char* data = [aData cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   unsigned char* digest;
   digest = HMAC(EVP_ripemd160(), key, (int)strlen(key), (unsigned char*)data, strlen(data), NULL, NULL);
   NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString string];
   for(int i = 0; i < RIPEMD160_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
      [str appendFormat:@"%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]];
   }
   return str;
}
```

I have setup an example for iOS based on Felix Schulze's [OpenSSL for iPhone library](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) that you can also compile for watchOS, macOS or tvOS.

1. Clone the [repository](https://github.com/jensmeder/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) from my GitHub account.
2. Open Terminal and change directory to the repository folder `cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone`
3. Run `./build-libssl.sh` to download and compile the openSSL sources
4. Open `OpenSSL-for-iOS.xcodeproj` with Xcode
5. Run `OpenSSL-for-iOS` on either iOS Simulator or on your phone

As you can see in the `ViewController.swift` you just need to call `FSOpenSSL.ripemd160(withKey: "test", andData: "string")` with the corresponding parameters. You can play with different values via the UI.

Hope that helps.

[image: Screenshot of iOS example app]